# How do I disable tabs for <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am using `<a>` tags for links on a web page. How do I disable the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key from selecting either of them?

Comment: Please be aware that in doing so, a website doing this might not be strictly legal in certain jurisdictions due to disability discrimination legislation.

Comment: Sounds like you are working for my bank.

Comment: For all the answers below: what's the easiest valid HTML?  tabindex=-1 doesn't validate, onblur seems excessive.

Comment: Here's a valid use case for this: A page has a big div that contains a link. If JavaScript is not enabled, everything works as you would expect. If JS is enabled, then on page load a script makes the entire div clickable and tabbable. To avoid confusion, the JavaScript should also make the link untabbable, otherwise tab will go from the div to the link, which is confusing.

Comment: Old question, but just chiming in support of @RowlandShaw 's comment that this sounds very much like a potential accessibility antipattern-- if you are preventing a keyboard-only user from accessing a links, you should have a very compelling reason to do so, otherwise you are potentially making your site inaccessible to users who cannot use a mouse, and are perhaps in violation of ADA or other local accessibility legislation.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

**EDIT:** Hi, original author of this answer here. Don't use this one. Scroll down. StackOverflow won't let me remove this answer since it was accepted.

---

You could do something like this for those links:

```
 <a href="http://foo.bar" onfocus="this.blur()">Can't focus on this!</a>
```

You should use the answer below, though.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/457115/974680

Comment: Thanks, Worked like a charm :)

Comment: Alex, that's why I updated my answer to say that it's better to use the one below.

Comment: I don't *understand* why this answer is getting thumbed down. 1) it's a working solution to the problem. 2) `tabindex="-1"` doesn't work in all browsers so this is a nice plan B. 3) Evan has **NO** control to accept this as the answer.  Come on people..

Comment: I agree with Jackson, ***but*** Evan should never use spatial references (eg *below*) to refer to another answer or post.  Instead, he should either update his answer, or refer to the content.  SO allows people to sort answers by *active*, *oldest*, and *votes*, so "below" could be referring to a bad answer and not necessarily the one he intended -- or it could be an answer in the comments.

Comment: It doesn't work in FF 15.0.1, so what`s the point? Also, after the link (with onfocus="this.blur();") all other tabs (after that link) do not work at all.

Comment: -1 would be a nightmare for visually impaired users that use screen readers and tab through the page, they wouldn't be able to tab beyond this link!

Comment: @Timm I would delete this answer if I could, but it won't let me since it's the accepted answer. I unfortunately have no control.

Comment: I remember the good old days when you could write javascript to eject someone's CDROM drive when they would visit your page. This is on par with that.

Answer (score 183):

Alternatively you could go for plain HTML solution.

```
<a href="http://foo.bar" tabindex="-1">inaccessible by tab link</a>
```

The [HTML5 spec says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#attr-tabindex):

> **If the value is a negative integer**
>   The user agent must set the element's tabindex focus flag, but should not allow the element to be reached using sequential focus navigation.

Comment: +1 Always favour non-script solutions (that work!) over non-script solutions.

Comment: Oddly enough people have not yet suggested a nowdays panacea solution - jQuery code sample

Comment: Does it validate against W3C HTML validator ?

Comment: @Evan - yeah I guess implicitly :)

Comment: It does not validate.  http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex says "This value must be a number between 0 and 32767." Is there an easy valid way to do this?

Comment: HTML 5 only requires that the number must be a valid integer, and if it is a negative value then the element cannot be focused using "Sequential Focus Navigation" (aka "tabbing"). http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#attr-tabindex

Comment: Oh but that is what we were trying to achieve.

Comment: This is really has to be answer

Comment: The correct casing for the attribute is tabindex, not tabIndex.

Comment: Love this solution!

If you need to do it with JS though you can do this :)
     $('#link').attr('tabindex',-1);

Answer (score 5):

I've had to prevent divs with and overflow: auto css rule from having a tab stop before and what I did was (transposed for a's):

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName( 'a' );

for( var i = 0, j =  links.length; i < j; i++ ) {
    links[i].setAttribute( 'tabindex', '-1' );
}
```

Using tabindex rather than blurring means the focus will skip to the next element.

Are you sure you want to disable tabindex though? It's kinda vital for navigation without a mouse.

Just noticed a similar answer in plain HTML

Comment: I have a tooltip with an awesome font, and the only way that it worked, so that I didn’t receive the focus and move directly to another field of the form was this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<a onfocus="this.blur();" href = "bla">Bla</a>
```

Comment: Beat me by 39 seconds, Nelson. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, Worked like a charm :)

Comment: Not nice for accessibility/laptop keyboard users/etc. As the focus cycles into the element it gets completely lost, making it impossible to tab onto the next link. Better to take it out of the regular tab cycle using a tabindex attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Tag `<a>` must be able to being tab-indexed. It makes navigation easier.

use `<p>` or `<span>` instead, width `onclick="window.location.href='URL'"` event attribute.

example:

```
<span onclick="window.location.href='http://www.w3schools.com'">text that redirects you to W3S on click, where you can read more about HTML standards.</span>
```

Comment: That would break keyboard navigation even worse, since even searching for links won't find it.