# loop focus of input fields inside a form

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form>
    <input tabindex="1" required>
    <input tabindex="2" required>
    <input>
    <input tabindex="3" required>
    <input>
    <input tabindex="4" required>
    <input tabindex="5" required>
    <button type="button" tabindex="6"></button>
    <button type="submit" tabindex="7"></button>
</form>
```

Here I have a `form` with some `input` fields and two `button` at the end of the form... and I am using `tabindex` attribute to `focus` them **in order**... now on tab key down I need to focus the **first input** field with `tabindex="1"` after **release focus** from the **submit button** as like as the **form focus** input field of `tabindex="3"` after **releasing focus** from input field of `tabindex="2"`... How can I do that...??

please don't use any jQuery... only javascript or html...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I disable tabs for <a> tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457070/how-do-i-disable-tabs-for-a-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have solved my problem... with HTML and a little javascript it can be done easily... means loop focus of input fields inside a form...

```
<form>
    <input tabindex="2" autofocus required>
    <input tabindex="3" required>
    <input>
    <input tabindex="4" required>
    <input>
    <input tabindex="5" required>
    <input tabindex="6" required>
    <button type="button" tabindex="7"></button>
    <button type="submit" tabindex="8" id=""
            onFocus="this.id=this.tabIndex;this.tabIndex=1"
            onBlur="this.tabIndex=this.id">
    </button>
</form>
```

Here I skip the `tabindex="1"` and start with `tabindex="2"`... then I add 2 more `attribute` in the `submit` button... `onFocus` & `onBlur`... moreover, I am using the `id` attribute to memory the primary or real tabindex number of the submit button... when the user will focus on the submit button, javascript will change its `tabindex` from `8` to `1`... now if the user hit the tab button the form will try to find out the element that have the next `tabindex`... means the first input field... again, when the focus will leave the submit button, javascript will retrieve its real `tabindex` from its `id`... means the `tabindex` will be changed from `1` to `8`... in this way the focus will keep looping inside the form...

[Live Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/3oqX41Br)

Answer (score 2):

Black Cobra's answer works, unless you're using your `id` attributes for something (which I was). It's easy enough to edit his code to work for anyone though:

```
<form>
    <input tabindex="2" autofocus required>
    <input tabindex="3" required>
    <input>
    <input tabindex="4" required>
    <input>
    <input tabindex="5" required>
    <input tabindex="6" required>
    <button type="button" tabindex="7"></button>
    <button type="submit" tabindex="8" id=""
            onFocus="this.tabIndex=1;"
            onBlur="this.tabIndex=8;">
    </button>
</form>
```

I just changed this:

```
        onFocus="this.id=this.tabIndex;this.tabIndex=1"
        onBlur="this.tabIndex=this.id">
```

to this:

```
        onFocus="this.tabIndex=1;"
        onBlur="this.tabIndex=8;">
```

It's not dynamic, but it's really easy. If you want dynamic, [see here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314659/how-to-repeat-the-tabindex-from-1-after-it-has-gone-to-the-last-element-with-a-t)