# How to repeat the tabindex from 1 after it has gone to the last element with a tabindex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabindex

So, for example, here's a script:

```
<!-- Random content above this comment -->
<input type="text" tabindex="1" />
<input type="text" tabindex="2" />
<input type="text" tabindex="3" />
<input type="text" tabindex="4" />
<input type="text" tabindex="5" />
<input type="text" tabindex="6" />
<!-- Nothing underneath this comment -->
```

So, when the user presses tab and goes through the six textboxes, reaches the last one and then presses tab, it would go to the content above the first comment, right? Well, how do I make it start from `tabindex="1"` again?

Comment: You can set `tabindex="-1"` for every element you don't want to belong to taborder, i.e. for every focusable element in "`Random content`" section of your code. [MSDN: tabindex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Couldn't find the page at MDN.)

Comment: **`document.body.tabIndex = '0'; document.body.focus(); document.body.tabindex = '-1'`** also you can just use the same tabindex if they're sequenced correctly in HTML

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do that without javascript. You can listen to a <kbd>TAB</kbd> (and make sure it's not <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>) key press on your last element and manually set the focus to your first element inside the handler. However, **binding this logic to keyboard events (i.e. specific input method) is not universal and may not work when using:**

- A mobile browser
- Some other entertainment device (smart tv, gaming console, etc. - they typically use a D-Pad for jumping between focusable elements)
- An accessibility service

I suggest a more universal approach which is agnostic of how the focus is changed.

The idea is that you surround your form elements (where you want to create a "*tabindex loop*") with special "focus guard" elements that are focusable too (they have a tabindex assigned). Here is your modified HTML:

```
<p>Some sample <a href="#" tabindex="0">content</a> here...</p>
<p>Like, another <input type="text" value="input" /> element or a <button>button</button>...</p>

<!-- Random content above this comment -->
<!-- Special "focus guard" elements around your
if you manually set tabindex for your form elements, you should set tabindex for the focus guards as well -->
<div class="focusguard" id="focusguard-1" tabindex="1"></div>
<input id="firstInput" type="text" tabindex="2" class="autofocus" />
<input type="text" tabindex="3" />
<input type="text" tabindex="4" />
<input type="text" tabindex="5" />
<input type="text" tabindex="6" />
<input id="lastInput" type="text" tabindex="7" />
<!-- focus guard in the end of the form -->
<div class="focusguard" id="focusguard-2" tabindex="8"></div>
<!-- Nothing underneath this comment -->
```

Now you just listen to `focus` events on those guard elements and manually change focus to the appropriate field (jQuery used for the sake of simplicity):

```
$('#focusguard-2').on('focus', function() {
  // "last" focus guard got focus: set focus to the first field
  $('#firstInput').focus();
});

$('#focusguard-1').on('focus', function() {
  // "first" focus guard got focus: set focus to the last field
  $('#lastInput').focus();
});
```

As you see, I also made sure that we snap back to the last input when the focus moves backwards from the first input (e.g. <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> on the first input). [Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/dipish/F82Xj/)

Note that the *focus guards* are assigned a tabindex value too to make sure they are focused immediately before/after your input fields. If you don't manually set tabindex to your inputs, then both focus guards can just have `tabindex="0"` assigned.

Of course you can make this all work in a dynamic environment as well, when your form is generated dynamically. Just figure out your [focusable elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870544/simplest-way-to-tab-only-through-focusable-descendants-of-a-particular-element?rq=1) (less trivial task) and surround them with the same focus guards.

Hope that helps, let me know if you have any issues.

**UPDATE**

As nbro pointed out, the above implementation has the unwanted effect of selecting the last element if one hits <kbd>TAB</kbd> after the page loads (as this would focus the first focusable element which is `#focusguard-1`, and that would trigger focusing the last input. To mitigate that, you can specify which element you want initially focused and focus it with another little piece of JavaScript:

```
$(function() { // can replace the onload function with any other even like showing of a dialog

  $('.autofocus').focus();
})
```

With this, just set the `autofocus` class on whatever element you want, and it'll be focused on page load (or any other event you listen to).

Comment: This method, though, if I understood correctly, will make the focus go to the last element if I first click on the tab button once the page is loaded, which isn't desirable...

Comment: @nbro True, this is an unfortunate side effect. But since this implementation requires "javascript intervention" anyway, it's not unreasonable to require also setting the initial focus via javascript as well. See updated answer.

Answer (score 10):

Here my solution where you no need any other elements. As you can see elements will be looping inside `<form>` elements.

```js
$('form').each(function(){
    var list  = $(this).find('*[tabindex]').sort(function(a,b){ return a.tabIndex < b.tabIndex ? -1 : 1; }),
        first = list.first();
    list.last().on('keydown', function(e){
        if( e.keyCode === 9 ) {
            first.focus();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: See the first part of my answer

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution, considering the first input has the "autofocus" attribute set:

Add this after your form element (with HTML5 it can be any tag):

```
<div tabindex="6" onFocus="document.querySelector('[autofocus]').focus()"></div>
```

Comment: This should be done on the event 'onFocusOut' instead of 'onFocus' as the last element will never be selected on a tab

Answer (score 1):

Yes, after tabbing through the inputs it will jump on suitable elements that do not have a tab order specified. But also, after tabbing all "tabbable" elements, the focus will jump "outside" your page content, onto the browser's UI elements (tabs, menus, bookmarks, etc)

I think the easiest way is to handle the `keyup` event on the last input and intercept <kbd>TAB</kbd> usage (and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> for that matter)

Comment: This is an old topic, however in today's multi-device world the problem's only become more relevant. The `keydown` approach has a downside, I added a more explicit clarificatio on that in my answer

Answer (score 0):

I wd suggest you to increase your tabindex ie. >100
 and also give the tabIndex to your "content" container div 
please note that your content container must have tabindex less than input boxes for ex.99 .

when you press tab on last input box manually set focus on your content div using javascript (you can use keypress handlers for tab key)

```
document.getElementById("content").focus();
```

you must giv tabindex to your "content" to set focus to it.

now if you press tab focus will automatically shift to first input box.

hope this will help.

Thank you