# Question about accessibility, looping back through a menu when tabbing?

Tags: html, accessibility

I got a simple question which I didn't know how to word and find the answer elsewhere...

So basically, when we have a hamburger menu, you click, the drawer shows up and then you tab through it to get to what you need. I'm wondering if there is a non-JS way to make it go back to the first element after the last one? Or is everyone doing a JS that detect the last item and then manually focus the first?

Thank you!

I couldn't try anything as I did not find any way to do it (other than JS).

Comment: This is known a focus trapping. I don't think it's possible without JavaScript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to repeat the tabindex from 1 after it has gone to the last element with a tabindex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314659/how-to-repeat-the-tabindex-from-1-after-it-has-gone-to-the-last-element-with-a-t)

Comment: Is the drawer modal? In other words, is an overlay preventing interaction with anything outside the menu drawer?

Answer (score 0):

If you implemented the modal dialog (the drawer) correctly, there is nothing you need to do.

With a modal dialog open, any interaction outside the dialog must be prohibited, including focusing elements outside the drawer.

The browser will automatically wrap around <kbd>Tab</kbd> as it would on any HTML page.

The fact that you would like to wrap focus indicates that you have a *modal* pattern. Also content access outside the dialog must be prohibited, then.

If interaction with elements outside the drawer should still be possible, you *must not* wrap focus, as you would establish a focus trap that the user cannot escape from.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

nav {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

main {
  opacity: .2;
}
```

```html
<main inert>
  <h1>Main Page Contents</h1>
  <p>This should not be exposed to assistive technology, and <a href="#">this link</a> should not be focusable.</p> 
</main>
<nav>
  <h2>The drawer</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

> [Inert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inert) does the following:
>
> - Prevents the `click` event from being fired when the user clicks on the element.
> - Prevents the `focus` event from being raised by preventing the element from gaining focus.
> - Hides the element and its content from assistive technologies by excluding them from the accessibility tree.